# Where can I find the managed rules list and source_identifier for terraform aws?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on creating a aws config with managed rule resource. It is easy to create managed rules on console, but it seems that it can not be done easily without writing a lot of code in terraform. Where can I find the managed rules list and source_identifier for terraform aws?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list with the managed rules in the AWS documentation: [List of AWS Config Managed Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/managed-rules-by-aws-config.html).

Please note, the source identifier in the Terraform module should be with uppercase and underscore. In the AWS docs, the source identifiers are with lowercase and dashes:

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "rule" {
  name = "example"

  source {
    owner             = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "S3_BUCKET_VERSIONING_ENABLED"
  }
}
```

For example, the equivalent of `S3_BUCKET_VERSIONING_ENABLED` in the AWS documentation is [`s3-bucket-versioning-enabled`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-versioning-enabled.html).